# Conf_path is deprecated but what is its replacement?

Tags: configuration, 8

Im upgrading a D7 module to D8 and it turns out conf_path() is deprecated but I cant find the replacement.

I found a github page that said use this

```
 DrupalKernel::findSitePath(Request::createFromGlobals())
```

but I still WSOD when that is called.

Comment: Are you importing the right namespaces in your code? Your server logs should contain a more detailed error if you're getting a WSOD

Comment: Are you using the [Drupal Module Upgrader](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalmoduleupgrader)? chances are that it will tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of two [change records](https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/drupal) for conf_path() is [Bootstrap refactored to use the kernel](https://www.drupal.org/node/2275139). This states that

> Note: In D8, instead of using conf_path(), [\Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel::getSitePath()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!DrupalKernel.php/function/DrupalKernel%3A%3AgetSitePath/8) instead. If the kernel is unavailable (such as above, where the code shows the booting of the D8 kernel) or the site path needs to be recalculated then Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel::findSitePath() can be used

So if you have access to the DrupalKernel object, then calling getSitePath() on that object will work. This is probably not the case.

However, there is a service for this called [site.path](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!SitePathFactory.php/class/SitePathFactory/8) that can be injected into a class that you need it. I think the change record could be updated to reference this factory class.

Using the global Drupal object:

```
$conf_path = \Drupal::service('site.path');
```

Comment: I get errors saying 'You have requested a non-existent service "site.path.factory"  when using that.

Comment: In addition if i use the \Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel::getSitePath()  i get an error for calling a non-static method statically

Comment: I modified my answer. I forgot that you can jut call "site.path" service and that just calls the factory.